# Laptop keyboard stopped working after installing a drawing tablet

Tags: windows-8, laptop, drivers, keyboard

The laptop in question is a Samsung series 7. The tablet (Turcom 6608) disk installed its own PS/2 keyboard driver among a copious amount of other HID drivers which I think  overrode the original one. Uninstalling via device manager doesn't change anything since Win8 update still finds and installs the two keyboards it installed even if it is unplugged. Removing other drivers does not work neither.

Caps lock doesn't light up, FN lock does. No other key responds to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe an app is conflicting?
try to unistall any Synaptics,ELAN or anything simlair in your programs and features list in the control panel

Comment: This gave me an idea to fish for the uninstaller that came with the tablet driver. It was in my System32 for some reason but it apparently at least removed everything that came with it and the keyboard is back online.